# Flutter's TextFormField doesn't work inside a Positioned widget

Tags: flutter, dart, stack, textfield

I'm trying to create an UI for a signup page with a little overlap between the container that contains the TextFormFields and the blue container that is only for decoration. But, when I do so, using a Stack widget and a Positioned to set the position of the white Container, my TextFormFields don't work (they don't open the keyboard when I click). The FlatButton I used also isn't working. I wonder what I'm doing wrong...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNwcV.jpg)

```
class TelaCadastro extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TelaCadastroState createState() => _TelaCadastroState();
}

final GlobalKey<FormState> _cadastroKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final TextEditingController _nomeController = TextEditingController();
final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
final TextEditingController _senhaController = TextEditingController();
final TextEditingController _confirmarSenhaController = TextEditingController();


class _TelaCadastroState extends State<TelaCadastro> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
        title: Text('Cadastrar'),
    ),
      body: Stack(
        overflow: Overflow.visible,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 17),
            color: Colors.indigo,
            height: 150,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 50,
                child: Text('A Corretora trabalha com as melhores '
                    'seguradoras do mercado',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21, color: Colors.white),),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 15,),
          Positioned(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 30,
            left: 15,
            top: 135,
            child: Container(
              height: 460,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
              ),
              child: Form(
                key: _cadastroKey,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(Icons.person_add, color: Colors.indigo,),
                          Text(' Cadastre-se abaixo!',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.indigo),),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 15),
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: _nomeController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))
                            ) ,
                            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
                            hintText: 'Nome Completo',
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Colors.grey[200]
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20,),
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: _emailController,
                        validator: (String texto){
                          if (texto.isEmpty || !texto.contains('@')){
                            return 'Por favor, informe um email válido';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))
                            ) ,
                            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                            hintText: 'Email',
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Colors.grey[200]
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20,),
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: _senhaController,
                        validator: (String texto){
                          if (texto.isEmpty || texto.length < 6){
                            return 'Por favor, informe uma senha válida';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))
                            ) ,
                            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                            hintText: 'Senha',
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Colors.grey[200]
                        ),
                        obscureText: true,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20,),
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: _confirmarSenhaController,
                        validator: (String texto){
                          if (texto.isEmpty || texto.length < 6){
                            return 'Por favor, informe uma senha válida';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))
                            ) ,
                            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                            hintText: 'Confirme sua Senha',
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Colors.grey[200]
                        ),
                        obscureText: true,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 30,),
                      Builder(
                        builder: (context) => Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 30,
                          height: 50,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.indigo,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))
                          ),
                          child: FlatButton(
                            child: Text('Criar Conta', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                            onPressed: (){
                              print('test');
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 15,)
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I had Commented your SizedBox widget and wrapped blue Container which is only for decoration with Positioned widget also giving appropriate width and height.

Now its completely working/!!

You can copy and paste run the full code below:-

```dart
class TelaCadastro extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TelaCadastroState createState() => _TelaCadastroState();
}

final GlobalKey<FormState> _cadastroKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
//final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final TextEditingController _nomeController = TextEditingController();
final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
final TextEditingController _senhaController = TextEditingController();
final TextEditingController _confirmarSenhaController = TextEditingController();

class _TelaCadastroState extends State<TelaCadastro> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          title: Text('Cadastrar'),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          overflow: Overflow.visible,
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
              width: 414,
              height: 150,
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 17),
                color: Colors.indigo,
                height: 150,
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 50,
                    child: Text(
                      'A Corretora trabalha com as melhores '
                      'seguradoras do mercado',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21, color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            // SizedBox(
            //   height: 15,
            // ),
            Positioned(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 30,
              left: 15,
              top: 135,
              child: Container(
                height: 460,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                ),
                child: Form(
                  key: _cadastroKey,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(
                              Icons.person_add,
                              color: Colors.indigo,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              ' Cadastre-se abaixo!',
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.indigo),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 15),
                        TextFormField(
                          controller: _nomeController,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide:
                                      BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide:
                                      BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
                              hintText: 'Nome Completo',
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: Colors.grey[200]),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          controller: _emailController,
                          validator: (String texto) {
                            if (texto.isEmpty || !texto.contains('@')) {
                              return 'Por favor, informe um email válido';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide:
                                      BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide:
                                      BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                              hintText: 'Email',
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: Colors.grey[200]),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          controller: _senhaController,
                          validator: (String texto) {
                            if (texto.isEmpty || texto.length < 6) {
                              return 'Por favor, informe uma senha válida';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide:
                                      BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide:
                                      BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                              hintText: 'Senha',
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: Colors.grey[200]),
                          obscureText: true,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          controller: _confirmarSenhaController,
                          validator: (String texto) {
                            if (texto.isEmpty || texto.length < 6) {
                              return 'Por favor, informe uma senha válida';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide:
                                      BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide:
                                      BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                              hintText: 'Confirme sua Senha',
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: Colors.grey[200]),
                          obscureText: true,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 30,
                        ),
                        Builder(
                          builder: (context) => Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 30,
                            height: 50,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.indigo,
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                            child: FlatButton(
                              child: Text(
                                'Criar Conta',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                print('test');
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 15,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```